# How to prevent default url decoding in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, decode, encode, .net-core-3.1

In my controller I have an HTTP get method that accepts a string

```
[HttpGet("{token}"]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFoo(string token) 
{
     //Some actine
     return Ok(object);
 }
```

If I send the below-encoded token `test%2Atest`, ASP .NET will decode this token to `test*test` by default. But if I send `test%2Ftest`, it does not decode the `%2F` to `/`.

I can understand why ASP.NET doesn't do that as it breaks the routes.

Is there a way to disable this default behavior so I can de the decoding in my controller?

Comment: It was already set as "[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]" in my base controller class.

Comment: By the way, if you just wanna avoid the string snippet like `%2F` within the token to be decoded, you may try to put the token into the request header. In my humble opinion, token always been put in the request header and I never saw anyone worry about the decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to disable default URL decoding in ASP.net core.

As Tiny Wang suggested above, I changed the application to send the token in the header and that fixed the problem.

Comment: We encountered the same problem but the work around is not a viable solution for us.

Answer (score 2):

You need encode token when generate with using
WebUtility.UrlEncode(token)

Also try to use next in controller for parsing %2F

```
string decodedUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Several test results in my side, but I don't think it's what you want.

[image]
[image]

I think if you can use this kind of parameter-receiving method?

```
https://localhost:44393/api/hello?token=test%2FParam

[HttpGet]
public string Index(string token)
{
    return token;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for doing this, we are building a RESTFul API, so not allowed to use the query string parameter

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing something similar, looking for a more "elegant" solution: just base64 encode the parameter before the request and decode it when you have to use it. I faced the same issue when sending an auto-generated email confirmation token through email and later an http request, and enconding it in base64 and decoding it when using it did the trick just fine.

Comment: That's not fundamental issue. It's the breaking change in .NET core described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-8.0